# SHA1 brute force program

Tags: hash, sha1, brute-force

Let said given two hash code, you have been given the value of character 1 to character 9. The remaining of characters are unknown. The message length is unknown too.

Happens that this two hash code generated from 2 different plaintext but only first character are different, the remaining of the characters are exactly the same.

```
First hash code = *********************
Second hash code = *********************
plaintext1 = 1************************ 
plaintext2 = 2************************
```

Able to brute force to recover the plaintext?

Comment: Hashes are designed such that even a slight change to the input will produce a vastly different output. Take a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect

Comment: Blender is right, Had slight changes won't have resulted in vastly different output, the very sole purpose of secured hash function is killed.

Answer (score 1):

Brute-forcing is always possible, it depends on your intention, whether it is applicable or not.

### Finding collision (password login)

If you only need to find a collision (a value that results in the same hash-value), brute-forcing is applicable. An off the shelf GPU is able to calculate [3 Giga](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat-lite/#performance) SHA1 hash values per second. That's why a fast hash function like SHA1 is a bad choice for hashing passwords, instead one should use a key derivation function like BCrypt or PBKDF2.

### Finding original password

Finding a collision will be relatively fast, finding the original password (not just a collision) can use more time, it depends on the strength of the password, how much time you need then.

With a good cryptographic hash function, the knowledge about same characters should give you no advantage.

### Modification of plaintext (digital signature)

If you want to alter the plaintext, so that it produces the same hash-value, then you will probably spend your life, looking for such a text. This is much harder, because the new text should make sense at last.

Answer (score 0):

Cryptographic hash algorithms are designed to spread small changes in the plaintext across the whole of the computed hash.  The kind of attack you're asking about is not feasible.